# Can you cast a memory address as a usize into a reference with a lifetime?

Tags: rust, unsafe

I know we can cast from reference -> raw pointer -> address (`usize`), but can we do it backwards especially with lifetime annotations? For example, I have following code:

```
struct Name<'a> {
    name: &'a str,
}

impl<'a> Name<'a> {
    fn to_addr<'b>(&'b self) -> usize { /* ... */ }
    fn from_addr<'b>(address: usize) -> &'b Name<'a> {
        // assuming the address is valid,
        // is this even possible to return an reference with both lifetimes?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's `unsafe`, but yes:

```
fn from_addr<'b>(address: usize) -> &'b Name<'a> {
    unsafe { &*(address as *const Self) }
}
```

You have to ensure Rust's memory safety requirements yourself: the pointer must be non-null, non-dangling, aligned, not mutably aliased, etc. on top of ensuring the lifetimes are correct.

I'd actually mark this whole function as `unsafe` since the lifetime `'b` (and depending on usage `'a`) is determined at the call-site. The caller should know that there are guarantees it needs to ensure in order to use it safely.

```
unsafe fn from_addr<'b>(address: usize) -> &'b Name<'a> {
    &*(address as *const Self)
}
```

Comment: The `as_ref` method on the pointers is also an option.